# ios tableViewCell.xib file generate more than one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uitableview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FIDCELL"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FriendTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FIDCELL"];
    return cell;
}
```

This code block work but when i add new cell in FriendTableViewCell.xib not work actually i can not call new cell. How can i call this cell or this is possible ? If this question is not clear i can add image...

**

> i try to call different cell from same .xib

**

[image: image 1]

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: Your code should definatley be generating more than one cell as long as you have additional data to add to more cells in your TableView. it would be helpful if you posted more code form your view controller.

Comment: please add images to clarify your question , are you trying to call different  cells form the same .xib ?

Comment: Has the new cell got an ID other than 'FIDCELL'?

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary yes true, i try to call different cell from same .xib this possible ? if possible how can i do that ?

Comment: I added image please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution i generate new .xib and call when page load both of them

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FIDCELL"];
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell2" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FIDCELL2"];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellID = @"";
    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cellID = @"FIDCELL";
    } else {
        cellID = @"FIDCELL2";
    }
    FriendTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.nameLabel.text = self.namesArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.photoNameArray[indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

This code part totally work.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so first of all , every cell should have its unique identifier so if the first cell have an identifier called "FIDCELL" the second one should have another one called "FIDCELL2" for example , and remove the following line from your viewDidLoad :

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FriendTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FIDCELL"];
```

and add this to cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell * cell ;
    if(condtion1)
    {
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:firstCellIdentfier];
    }
    else if(condtion2)
    {
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:secondCellIdentfier];
    }
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:yourNibName owner:self options:nil];
        if(condtion1)
        {
           //0 is the index of the first cell in the nib
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        else if(condtion2)
        {
           //1 is the index of the second cell in the nib .
           cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1] ; 
        }

    }
       //do other work 
   return cell ;
}
```

where condtion1 and and condtion2 is the conditions that will determine which cell will be chosen .